# Как "опустить" несколько подстрок?

Tags: delphi, текст

Текст в memo представлен в таком виде:

```
http://сайтhttp://сайт2http://сайт3http://сайт4 и.т.д.
```

как сделать так что бы URL'ы были в столбик, то есть:

```
http://сайт1
http://сайт2
http://сайт3
```

Пробовал так:

```
s:=StringReplace(s, 'http://', ' http://', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
```

но ничего не вышло

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Либо так

```
s:=StringReplace(s, 'http://', '\nhttp://', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
```

либо

```
s:=StringReplace(s, 'http://', #13#10+'http://', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
```

либо можно ещё

```
Memo.Lines.Add("http://url 1");
Memo.Lines.Add("http://url 2");
Memo.Lines.Add("http://url 3");
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 2):

Вот тут описано как работать с memo - [ссылка](http://www.delphi-manual.ru/memo.php)

Как понял необходимо просто каждый url запихивить в memo вот так - по отдельности

```
Memo1.Lines.Add(url)
```